# Rails: Foundation 5 Reveal Modal to Submit Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, zurb-foundation

I have a form in which half of it is on a "*Targeting*" Reveal Modal. For example, the user will fill out certain fields in the form, click a next (in which is named "*Define Targeting*") button in which a modal pops up to finish the form.

When they click the "*Done*" submit button, I would like it to save and close the modal and stay on the main form page.

The issue I am having is that it does not save my record as long as I have the `class: "close-reveal-modal"`. When removed, it saves the record but it does then I lose it's ability to close the modal.

Here is the submit button..

```
<%= f.submit "Done", class: "close-reveal-modal", remote: true %>
```

..and extra Javascript to trigger the submit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close-reveal-modal").click(function(){

        var isSelected = $("#campaign_plan_id").val();

        if (isSelected.length > 0){
            $('form#new_campaign').trigger('submit.rails');
            $("#target-button").hide();
            $("#campaign-create-button").css("display", "block").css("background-color", "#E37368");
        }
    });
})
```

Let me know if more clarity is needed and I'd be happy to add to the post. I'm learning Zurb through this process and Javascript isn't necessarily my forte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the class name to sth like `close-button` and then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close-button").click(function(){

        var isSelected = $("#campaign_plan_id").val();

        if (isSelected.length > 0){
            $('form#new_campaign').trigger('submit.rails');
            $("#target-button").hide();
            $("#campaign-create-button").css("display", "block").css("background-color", "#E37368");
        }

        $(this).closest('[data-reveal]').foundation('reveal', 'close');
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a step forward but it's not saving the attributes/fields that are selected in the modal, only the one's on the main page. Also it doesn't look like AJAX is working as it sent me to the `#show` page of the incomplete saved record. I will update my post above soon.

Comment: @Shroy - And there is your main problem now. :) Foundation had this great idea to move all reveal modals out of their initial location in DOM - which means  that at the point you open the modal, it moves to the very bottom of the body and as result - out of your form. The only workaround I found so far is to copy the content of the modal and append it to the form before submission (with `display: none` naturally)

Comment: Took a little work but I did what you mentioned and now have it working! Thanks for the help!